# kubernetes: Elaboration of OOM message in cluster events

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working on GKE.

Sometimes I see the following message in my GKE Cluster Operations (which I assume reports the counterpart of `kubectl get events`)

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 670233 (java) score 1728 or sacrifice child
Killed process 670233 (java) total-vm:16535056kB, anon-rss:10437020kB, file-rss:20112kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

The specific pod has the following resources

```
          limits:
            cpu: 4096m
            memory: 10Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 1024m
            memory: 8Gi
```

Should I assume the OOM takes place because the pod is reaching > 10Gi (which is the limit)?

My question stems from the fact that when a pod reaches its mem limit, killing it should be handled by the `kubelet`.

The above seems to be a `node`-level event (`cgroup` related event to be more precise) however.

Could it be just coincidental the fact that the sum of Resident Set Size (`rss-*`) is just above `10Gi` which is the pod's limit?

Answer (score 0):

This question was in the most part already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654979/how-to-interpret-this-kernel-message-cgroup-out-of-memory-kill-process-1234) by Rico:

---

I believe this is actually answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282155/what-is-the-out-of-memory-message-sacrifice-child)

If you check the Linux kernel code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/oom_kill.c). You'll see:

```
/*
 * If any of p's children has a different mm and is eligible for kill,
 * the one with the highest oom_badness() score is sacrificed for its
 * parent.  This attempts to lose the minimal amount of work done while
 * still freeing memory.
 */
```

mm means 'Memory Management'.

The only difference here is that this kill is getting triggered by cgroups because you have probably run into memory limits.

---

And for the second part:

> Should I assume the OOM takes place because the pod is reaching > 10Gi
>   (which is the limit)?

Yes, your pod has a limit set and that's being reached.